# Enabling remote docker access via tcp with 127.0.0.1:2375 fails but work when using 0.0.0.0:2375

Tags: docker, ubuntu, networking, docker-daemon

I'm currently running Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to expose remote docker access via tcp with the `systemd` approach, as listed in the official [docker guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#configuring-remote-access-with-systemd-unit-file).

```
# config in docker.service.d
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
```

However I noticed that it only works when IP address is listed as `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

May I know what could have resulted in it working only with `0.0.0.0:2375` and is there any significant difference using either loopback address?

Comment: Using 0.0.0.0 will let anyone who can connect to the system **trivially root the entire host**.  127.0.0.1 will only let any process running locally on the system use Docker for privilege escalation.  Unencrypted network-accessible Docker is a **critical security problem** and you should consider whether you need to reinstall this system with this option disabled and update any passwords that could have been on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation directs you to change the lines as per your needs. When you use `127.0.0.1` the daemon will listen on the loopback interface and thus will not be accessible from the network. A loopback interface is only meant to be accessible on the same host.

When you use `0.0.0.0` (not a loopback, but a special address meaning any interface, thus including whatever interface(s) you have connected to the network), network requests reaching your host on port 2375 will be routed to your daemon.

Update: you may think of it this way. The IP you specify as `-H <IPv4>:2375` identifies the interface the daemon will listen to. It is the destination IP of requests from the network, and the source IP of the replies from the daemon. 127.0.0.1 corresponds to a loopback interface, and you could use e.g. 192.168.1.54 if that would be one of your IP addresses. 0.0.0.0 is a special address meaning "listen on all my interfaces".

Comment: trying to understand the `-H, --host` flag for dockerd when listed as `dockerd -H tcp://[IPv4]:2375`. Is the IP address portion listing the source IP?

Comment: @Dric, I've tried to answer this in an update.